# Como criar COLLATION para Português Brasileiro

Tags: postgresql, codificação-de-caracteres, locale

Na [documentação](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-createcollation.html) diz para criar o `collation` assim:

```
CREATE COLLATION french (LOCALE = 'fr_FR.utf8');
```

Esse exemplo é para França. Como seria para português brasileiro?

Answer (score 3):

pt_BR.utf8

Para verificar quais os locales disponíveis use:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_collation;
```

Comment: E quando não tem o pt_BR.utf8 disponível?

Comment: Neste caso você tem que pesquisar como instalar em seu sistema operacional.

Answer (score 0):

Para quem estiver querendo resolver o problema de COLLATION no PostgreSQL, eu resolvi da seguinte forma:

Crie seu banco de dados normalmente:

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS db_vendas;
CREATE DATABASE db_vendas
WITH OWNER "postgres"
TEMPLATE template0;
```

Após logar no novo database, em MODO EXCLUSIVO, execute:

```
-- Confira se você está no database certo:  
SELECT session_user, current_database();
```

Crie um COLLATE do tipo ci e ai:

```
-- criar o COLLATE case_insensitive (ci) e accent_insencitive (ai) 
-- DROP COLLATION general_ci_ai;   
CREATE COLLATION general_ci_ai (
    PROVIDER = icu,
    DETERMINISTIC = FALSE,
    LOCALE = 'pt-u-ks-level1'
);
```

O LOCALE 'pt-u-ks-level1' quer dizer o seguinte:

- pt : Portugues;
- -u- : separador;
- ks-level1 : "collation strength", onde 'level1' significa “case and accent insensitive” e 'level2' apenas "case insensitive';

Crie suas tabelas com os campos varchar com o COLLATE acima:

```
create table public.usuario(
    id serial not null, 
    nome varchar(128) COLLATE "general_ci_ai" NOT NULL,
    email varchar(256) COLLATE "general_ci_ai" NOT NULL     
)
```

Versão testada (Docker):

```
PostgreSQL 15.4 (Debian 15.4-2.pgdg120+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0, 64-bit
```

Comment: Conectar de MODO EXCLUSIVO é conectar via URL incluindo o seu database. Exemplo:  jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db_vendas